# PJSUA Makefile error: Invalid use of non-static data member 'param'

Tags: c++, c, pjsip

Working with pjsua and the pjsua-jni folder I have run into a error. Being new to C and C++ I have just learning as I go. I have experience with programming so I am not that out of my league, I hope.

The errors I get from the make file is

```
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3843:23: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'param'
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *arg2 ;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3843:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'arg2'
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *arg2 ;
                         ^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3849:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'arg2'
arg2 = *(pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param **)&jarg2; 
^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3849:32: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'param'
arg2 = *(pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param **)&jarg2; 
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3849:40: error: expected expression
arg2 = *(pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param **)&jarg2; 
                                   ^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3852:25: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'param'
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *b = (pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg1->param;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3852:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *b = (pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg1->param;
                           ^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3852:57: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'param'
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *b = (pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg1->param;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3852:64: error: expected expression
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *b = (pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg1->param;
                                                           ^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3853:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'
for (ii = 0; ii < (size_t)8; ii++) b[ii] = *((pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg2 + ii);
                                   ^
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3853:71: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'param'
for (ii = 0; ii < (size_t)8; ii++) b[ii] = *((pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg2 + ii);
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
nativesrc/pjsua_wrap.cpp:3853:78: error: expected expression
for (ii = 0; ii < (size_t)8; ii++) b[ii] = *((pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *) arg2 + ii);
```

I am not sure how to declare this param. When looking in the codecs.h file I find this

```
typedef struct pjmedia_codec_fmtp
{
  pj_uint8_t      cnt;            /**< Number of parameters.          */
  struct param {
    pj_str_t    name;           /**< Parameter name.                */
    pj_str_t    val;            /**< Parameter value.               */
  } param [PJMEDIA_CODEC_MAX_FMTP_CNT]; /**< The parameters.          */
} pjmedia_codec_fmtp;
```

So the way its calling the param struct is `pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *arg2`. Is that right? I know that the `::` usually is how you call a static method but is that how you call structs too?

Anyway help would be great

This is the code it throws the first error on

```
pjmedia_codec_fmtp *arg1 = (pjmedia_codec_fmtp *) 0 ;
pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *arg2; // Error
```

Comment: `pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param` is an non-static array of `PJMEDIA_CODEC_MAX_FMTP_CNT` objects of type `struct pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param`... I would highly suggest picking a different name either for the array or for the struct... Maybe both... Actually, scratch the "maybe"...

Comment: Well I would rather avoid changing the pjsip library and focus on the way I call it.

Comment: Well, in that case you're going to have to make your declarations look like `struct pjmedia_codec_fmtp::param *arg2;` - with the explicit `struct` at the front to disambiguate from the member variable of the same name.

Comment: What pjsip version are you using? Have you done any changes to pjsua_app.h? I mean, pjsua_wraper.cpp is created by swig based on pjsua_app.h and, in this header file, there's no reference to pjmedia_codec_fmtp at all.